# CSS background in IE 6 & 7 on a div

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, background-image

full CSS file : http://pastebin.com/9LjYjiUF

```
.body-content{
    background-image: white url("images/content-bg.gif");
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-position: left bottom;

}
```

this is the html:

```
<div class="content-bead bg2 rockwell">

    <div class="body-content">

        <div class="body-content-sub">
            <div id="content-left">

            </div>
            <div id="content-main">

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

== updated css===

```
background-image: url(images/content-bg.gif);
background-repeat: repeat-y;
background-position: left bottom;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
```

still nothing
i cant get the background image to come up at all. on

Comment: Is it working in other browsers? Have you double checked the location of the image?

Comment: I get an unknown pastebin id error, when opening the link

Answer (score 5):

That's because background-image is not a combined property. either pick them apart:

```
background-image: url('images/content-bg.gif');
background-color: white;
```

or combine them:

```
background: white url('images/content-bg.gif') left bottom repeat-y;
```

Answer (score 1):

give overflow:auto a try on the container with the bg, it might be that floated elements inside need to be cleared. Just experienced this problem with IE7 but worked fine in all other browsers

Answer (score 0):

maybe remove white as it is not part of "background-image"
or change it to "background"

Answer (score 0):

remove white value.

```
.body-content{
  background-image: url("images/content-bg.gif");
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-position: left bottom;
}
```